# Pressure Sensor KP125, input Pressure to O/P voltage conversion,

Tags: sensor

According to the KP125 Pressure sensor [datasheet](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/_media/pdfs/datasheets/components/sensor-pressure-kp125.pdf), the KP125 has an input pressure range from 40 kPa to 115 kPa.
Applied pressure is transferred to an analog output voltage between 0.5 and 4.5 V.

If the input pressure to the Sensor is 80kPa, then how would I suppose to know the output analog voltage, since there is no mention of any step-size or a scale factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 9 of datasheet.  Its linear.

So, 115kpa - 40kpa = 75kpa range.

80kpa - 40kpa = 40kpa above minimum.

4.5v - .5v = 4 volt range.

So, 40kpa * 4v / 75kpa = 2.13v + .5v = 2.63v

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet shows the calibration curve in fig.3.  By eyeball, you can see that 80 kPa would correspond to ≈2.6 V

Notice that the calibration curve is linear.  As you've noticed already, the datasheet gives you two points on the curve.  That allows you to calculate the slope of 0.053 V/kPa.